# Record Video while doing Image processing through CameraX in Android

Tags: android, image-processing, android-camera, android-camerax, video-recording

I am doing image processing by using CameraX, it is working fine. I want to record video too while doing image processing.
Is it possible? If yes then how?

I am doing image processing as:

```
ImageAnalysis.Builder builder = new ImageAnalysis.Builder();
    builder.setBackpressureStrategy(ImageAnalysis.STRATEGY_KEEP_ONLY_LATEST);
    analysisUseCase = builder.build();
    analysisUseCase.setAnalyzer(
            ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(SetAndGetData.getInstance().getContext()),
            imageProxy -> {
                 // doing image processing here.....
            });
    cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(this, cameraSelector, analysisUseCase);
```

I want to record video too while doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Do this in opencv

declare this

`VideoWriter output = new VideoWriter();`

open file to write

`output.open("/sdcard/movies/analysis_" + currentDateandTime + ".avi", CAP_OPENCV_MJPEG, VideoWriter.fourcc('M', 'J', 'P', 'G'), 15, new Size(480,640), true);`

then inside analyzer

`if(output.isOpened()) output.write(img);`

to terminate

`output.release`